# jQuery / Javascript frame content and .contents() example not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a .asp page that loads some frames and I need to access their content.

I tried to use jquery .contents() method by replicating the official example from the documentation but even that doesn't work.

Here's my code snippets

HOME.HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contents demo</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="mycom.html" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>

<script>
$( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( "div" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

MYCOM.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="foo"><H1>MYCOM FRAME!</H1></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also using `.load` on the frame to ensure that its content is fully loaded does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: edit: iframe example works using .load method with jquery. But why i've no lock using frameset and frames with the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your question.

[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe?rq=1)

Your code is OK, but you can't access iframes from a different domain as your page.

Comment: I'm not getting any error about the origin domain. Pages are on the same folder

Comment: if you load load the pages from a local folder you get the same domain error. You have to load the pages through a server